# Java Net basic Client to Server message

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Hey I'm trying to grasp some basic networking. So far I've got a small program to work which starts a server, connects a client which sends a message to the server.

Now I'm trying to make the server respond once, so to sum it up:

- Server Starts
- Client Connects, sends message
- Server receives message, displays it and sends a message back
- Client displays servers message and exits

But I can't get it to work, it stops working after the client has successfully connected. 
Here's the client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 5151);
        String msg = "Hello, I am a Client.";

        if(sock.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected to server!");
        }

        OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(ostream);
        dos.writeBytes(msg);

        InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
        String msgBack = br1.readLine();

        System.out.println(msgBack);

        br1.close();
        dos.close();
        ostream.close();
        sock.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not conenct to server.");
    }
}
```

}

And the Server:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(5151);
    System.out.println("Server is running!");

    Socket client = sock.accept();
    System.out.println("Client connected from " + client.getLocalAddress());

    InputStream istream = client.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(istream);

    String msg = dis.readLine();

    System.out.println(msg);

    OutputStream ostream = client.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ostream));

    String msgBack = "Thank you for connecting!";
    bw1.write(msgBack);

    bw1.close();
    dis.close();
    istream.close();
    client.close();
    sock.close();

}
```

}

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is not working? Add stack trace and exception you encounter.

Comment: I don't get any direct errors, it just that it "freezes" after the client has connected, like it's waiting for something.

Comment: Well, your server is blocked waiting for a newline in `String msg = dis.readLine();`. Since your client doesn't send one the server just waits forever. If you change the client line to `dos.writeUTF(msg)` and the server line to `String msg = dis.readUTF()` then it makes more sense

Comment: You can always try to step the code with debugger to find out where did the program froze.